# Unity camera problem - Moving FPS/TPS camera to look at a target and resuming player control

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am having trouble with aligning my player controlled camera (I use the same class for FPS and TPS) to look at a target (when `ResetCamera()` is called by another script) and then getting the player to resume control. The main reason I am doing this is so I can switch between FPS and TPS cameras and remain looking at the same target.

I can look at the target fine, but ONLY if I stop setting the rotation based on `yaw` and `pitch` (from `"Mouse X"` and `"Mouse Y"` inputs) in `LateUpdate()` after I set the `lookAtTarget` in `ResetCamera()`, but that means the player can no longer look around.
However, I cannot figure out how to get the correct `yaw` and `pitch` values after this so the player can continue looking around from the new look at target. How could I do this so the player could continue looking around?

```
public class PlayerCamera : MonoBehaviour {

    public float mouseSensitivity = 10f;
    public Transform target;
    public float dstFromTarget = 2f;
    public Vector2 pitchConstraints = new Vector2(-20f, 85f);

    public float rotSmoothTime = .12f;
    Vector3 rotSmoothVel;
    Vector3 currRot;

    float yaw;
    float pitch;

    void LateUpdate() {
        yaw += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity;
        pitch -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity;
        pitch = Mathf.Clamp(pitch, pitchConstraints.x, pitchConstraints.y);

        currRot = Vector3.SmoothDamp(currRot, new Vector3(pitch, yaw), ref rotSmoothVel, rotSmoothTime);
        transform.eulerAngles = currRot;

        transform.position = target.position - transform.forward * dstFromTarget;
    }

    public void ResetCamera(Transform lookAtTarget) {
        transform.LookAt(lookAtTarget);

        // below gets yaw and pitch values that move the camera to look at the
        // wrong location
        // yaw = transform.eulerAngles.x;
        // pitch = transform.eulerAngles.y;
        // pitch = Mathf.Clamp(pitch, pitchConstraints.x, pitchConstraints.y);
        // currRot = new Vector3(pitch, yaw);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out how to do what I  wanted. Below is a script for a third or first person (just adjust the dstFromTarget variable to zero) camera that can be rotated to look at a target by another script with ResetCamera() and the player can resume moving around from that point.

```
public class PlayerCamera : MonoBehaviour {

public bool isFirstPerson = false;
public float mouseSensitivity = 10f;
public Transform target;
public float dstFromTarget = 2f;
public bool invertedPitch = false;
public float smoothTime = .12f;

public float minimumX = -85f;
public float maximumX = 85f;

// LateUpdate, so the Camera Target will definitely have been set
void LateUpdate () {
    // first person updating is handled by Inverse kinematics stuff in my case
    if (isFirstPerson) return;
    UpdateStuff();
}

public void UpdateStuff() {
    float yaw = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X");
    float pitch = -Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y");
    if (invertedPitch) {
        pitch *= -1f;
    }

    Vector3 yRot = new Vector3(0f, yaw, 0f) * mouseSensitivity;
    Vector3 xRot = new Vector3(pitch, 0f, 0f) * mouseSensitivity;

    xRot = ClampRotationAroundXAxis(transform.rotation, xRot);

    Transform newTrans = transform;
    newTrans.Rotate(xRot);
    newTrans.Rotate(yRot, Space.World);

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, newTrans.rotation, smoothTime * Time.deltaTime);

    transform.position = target.position - transform.forward * dstFromTarget;
}

public void ResetCamera(Transform lookAtTarget) {
    transform.LookAt(lookAtTarget);
}

Vector3 ClampRotationAroundXAxis(Quaternion q, Vector3 xrot) {
    q.x /= q.w;
    q.y /= q.w;
    q.z /= q.w;
    q.w = 1.0f;

    float angleX = 2.0f * Mathf.Rad2Deg * Mathf.Atan (q.x);

    if (angleX < minimumX && xrot.x < 0f) {
        xrot = Vector3.zero;
    }
    if (angleX > maximumX && xrot.x > 0f) {
        xrot = Vector3.zero;
    }

    return xrot;
}
```

}